# Xcode - Selection dependent TableView lists

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I would like to create a selection dependency list but I don't know what would be the best way to do it in my app.

[selection dependency list example](http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8488/8175125633_fc4de9520b_z.jpg)

Based on the user choice from the first list they will be given another list with additional options. Additional lists will contain different data. After going through all the pick from the list options user will see a final table view with all the items they selected in the process.

I was thinking of creating a TableView containing all the list options.
Selecting only one item from the TableView will move user to another TableView with another list dependend on his previous choice.

Unfortunately, by doing it this way, I will end up having 13 different TableView Controllers on my storyboard and it just doesn't feels right.

I am sure there must be another more efficient way of doing this, but I just don't know how.

Please advice, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITableViewDataSource` protocol to the rescue.  It's intended to solve this exact problem.  You'll write one `UITableViewController`, and then just swap in a different `UITableViewDataSource` for each list.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Typically, as is the case of most examples around the web, the `datasource` property of `UITableViewController` is set to `self`.  But this is why it's there, so you don't have to copy/paste `UITableViewController` code everywhere when your just modifying how the data is generated for the table.

Depending how "different" your datasets are, you may not even need a separate `UITableViewDataSource`, and instead just modify the data structures you are using within your only `UITableViewDataSource`.

At a high level, your design might look like:

- BookStoreTableViewController
- BookListTableViewDataSource
- AuthorListTableViewDataSource
- PublisherListTableViewDataSource
- etc.

Here's an example method to show a different list:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BookStoreTableViewController *controller = [[BookStoreTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BookStoreTableViewController" bundle:nil];

    //This is where you'd need to put some logic to determine which datasource to use

    BookListTableViewDataSource *datasource = [[BookListTableViewDataSource alloc] init];
    datasource.listOfBooks = [bookstoreDictionary objectForKey:@"bookList"];
    controller.datasource = datasource;
    [datasource release];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [controller release];
}
```